# Past perfect or Simple past correct use

Tags: sentence-construction

Which one is more correct ?

A) Remain on the chair until lift has stopped.

B) Remain on the chair until lift is stopped.

Also,

A) Do not attempt to leave the lift until the landing gate is opened fully.

B) Do not attempt to leave the lift until the landing gate has opened fully.

Answer (score 1):

Your first sentence is missing a `the` in front of `lift`.

Assuming that is in, the the one that is more correct is A because both tenses match (`has` and `stopped`):

`Remain on the chair until the lift has stopped.`

Although, I would probably rewrite this sentence as:

`Please remain seated until the lift has stopped.`

For the 2nd sentence, B) is correct, but A can be rewritten to say:

A) `Do not attempt to leave the lift until the landing gate is fully open.`

Like the above, both of the tenses need to match for it to be correct (although in the 1st set of sentences, `is` and `stop` wouldn't make sense because `stop` is not an adjective unlike `stopped`).

I do prefer the "fully" to precede the word "open" in both cases.